# row number partition mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

what is wrong with this

```
select 
ID
,SYSCODE
,LID
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SYSCODE, LID) AS row_num
 from prod_sys.P_ENTERPRISE
```

it works in management studio but not in mysql workbench

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Error message? Unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

ROW_NUMBER() is not there in MYSQL, rewrite the query like below.

```
select 
ID
,SYSCODE
,LID
,@row_num := @row_num + 1 as Row_number
 from prod_sys.P_ENTERPRISE join (SELECT @row_num := 0) a;
```